# C++ Strange characters appear when writing to text file

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, text, fstream

I have a program that writes out the frame number and current system time whenever a picture is taken on a camera:

```
SYSTEMTIME st;
GetSystemTime(&st);
lStr.Format( _T("%d   %d.%d.%d.%d\r\n"),GetFrames() ,st.wHour, st.wMinute, st.wSecond, st.wMilliseconds);

std::wfstream myfile;  
myfile.open("test.txt", std::ios::out | std::ios::in | std::ios::app );
    if (myfile.is_open())
            {
            myfile.write((LPCTSTR)lStr, lStr.GetLength()*sizeof(TCHAR));
            myfile.close();
            }
        else {lStr.Format( _T("open file failed: %d"), WSAGetLastError());
        }
```

The text file that the program outputs seems to write the data correctly, but I get spaces and characters that shouldn't be there at the start of each line. The website doesn't seem to format the spaces correctly so i'll post a picture, this is what the text file looks like. The file also shows bullet points sometimes in addition to the zero's.

[image]

As you can see the first line is fine but it seems to get worse the longer I write to the text file. The program is writing to the file about 10 times every second. I am new to C++ and I am not sure what could be causing this. I tried to look for other questions similar to this but they didn't seem to have a solution I was looking for. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What does GetFrames return? Int?

Comment: I have a suspicion it is the `\r\n` at the end of the line. As you open it in text format (IE, not binary) \n will be automatically translated to '\r\n' on Windows.

Comment: It is a DWORD, should I be using a DWORD?

Comment: DWORD is unsigned long, which is fine.

Comment: ok so does that mean that if I get rid of the \r windows will still recognize it as \r\n?

Comment: Though technically you should be using %lu in the printf

Comment: Yes that is correct. Removing \r will still have \r\n in the file.

Comment: Try making those 2 changes and see what happens, but it probably won't fix it.

Comment: What is the type of lStr? Is it CString?

Comment: yes that is a lot better, I am no longer getting the zeros or as many spaces but I am still getting a couple of spaces. Yes the lStr is a CString.

Comment: The second parameter of `wfstream::write` is the size of the buffer in characters, not in bytes as you appear to assume. You write `n` characters of the string, and then `n` characters of random garbage that happens to follow in memory. Drop `* sizeof(TCHAR)` part.

Comment: That's what I was missing @IgorTandetnik. I'll leave it to you to write an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution has 2 parts:

```
lStr.Format( _T("%d   %d.%d.%d.%d\r\n"),GetFrames() ,st.wHour, st.wMinute, st.wSecond, st.wMilliseconds);
```

should be

```
lStr.Format( _T("%lu   %d.%d.%d.%d\n"),GetFrames() ,st.wHour, st.wMinute, st.wSecond, st.wMilliseconds);
```

As `GetFrames()` returns `DWORD` which is `unsigned long` and you are writing the file as text so `\n` is converted to `\r\n` if needed, depending on the operating system.

The other part is that the second parameter of `wfstream::write` is number of characters not number of bytes so

```
myfile.write((LPCTSTR)lStr, lStr.GetLength()*sizeof(TCHAR));
```

should be

```
myfile.write((LPCTSTR)lStr, lStr.GetLength());
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use [`std::wfstream::write`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/basic_ostream/write/) (basic_ostream), it takes the size of your string. You multiply that size again with `* sizeof(TCHAR)`. Removing this additional multiply should simply fix your problem.

---

Though if you have anywhere else issues (e.g. a third-party library returns with too many spaces), you could always trim the string.

A basic example for this:

```
template<class TString>
static inline TString &trim_left(TString &s)
{
    s.erase(std::begin(s), std::find_if(std::begin(s), std::end(s), std::not1(std::ptr_fun<int, int>(std::isspace))));
    return s;
}

template<class TString>
static inline TString &trim_right(TString &s)
{
    s.erase(std::find_if(s.rbegin(), s.rend(), std::not1(std::ptr_fun<int, int>(std::isspace))).base(), std::end(s));
    return s;
}

template<class TString>
static inline TString &trim(TString &s)
{
    return trim_left(trim_right(s));
}
```